# How to store required module in a dictionary in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, module, module.exports

I just want to store my already required module in a dictionary like this:

Vars.js:

```
var userJackModule = require("./userJackModule");

module.exports = {
    users: 
    {
        "jack": 
        {
          "jsFile": userJackModule
        },
    },
```

userJackModule.js:

```
var Vars = require("./vars")

module.exports = {
    balance: 0,
    
    changeBalance : function (newBalance)
    {
       this.balance = newBalance;
    }
};
```

There is a `userJackModule.balance` variable exported in `userJackModule.js`, but I can't access it by doing `users["jack"]["jsFile"].balance`. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Did you look at `users["jack"]["jsFile"].exports`?

Comment: @Anatoly yes, however it's`undefined`

Comment: Can you add a part of `userJackModule` with `balance` and exports? And also that code that you use to import a module with `users` in exports and where you look at `users["jack"]["jsFile"].balance`

Comment: @Anatoly I edited my question. Also the Vars.js and userJackModule.js are both imported where I'm trying to access it like `Vars.users["jack"]["jsFile"].balance`

Comment: Please show how you imported and used Vars.js

Comment: @Anatoly I finally solved it! I'm new to node.js, seems like I encountered something known as "Circular Dependency". There are plenty of tutorials to how to overcome with it on the web. I solved it by creating another "Vars" file and importing the second Vars file in userJackModule instead of the first one. Thanks for your help I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

userJackModule.js

```js
var Vars = require("./vars")

module.exports = {
    balance: 0,
    
    changeBalance : function (newBalance)
    {
       this.balance = newBalance;
    }
};
```

Vars.js:

```js
var userJackModule = require("./userJackModule");

module.exports = {
    users: 
    {
        "jack": 
        {
          "jsFile": userJackModule
        },
    },
};
```

app.js

```js
const vars = require('./Vars');
console.log(vars.users.jack.jsFile.balance);
```

this is printing 0;